# RestAngular - Injector module error

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm totally new to the Restangular and trying to learn it by implementing a simple application by calling a webapi. I'm able to call this service with simple $http service and getting the correct response.

The code I have written is as below.
I have googled the issue to find the solution but no like.

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['restangular']);

myApp.config(function (RestangularProvider) {
    var newBaseUrl = "";

        newBaseUrl = 'http://localhost:37103/api/'

    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(newBaseUrl);
})

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, Restangular) {
    $scope.data = "Default Value"
    $scope.data = Restangular.one("employee").get();
})
```

The error which I'm getting on chromes console is as below

```
 angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…0Bc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A37103%2FSource%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A179)
```

The above error is clickable and it says may be the file is mot included. But I have included the restangular.js file and I could see it getting loaded in the network tab.

Thanks!

Comment: You've truncated the error. it contains full information on what's wrong. And actually is clickable and leads to the page that explains what's wrong. Please, fix it. This would happen you haven't loaded restangular js file.

Comment: Hi estus. I had already included all the files but still the error persisted. I simply replaced the local js files with cdn tag http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/restangular/1.5.1/restangular.js and it worked. Its really strange :/. Thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue I found something was wrong in the restangular.js file which I downloaded. I replaced it with the cdn tag cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/restangular/1.5.1/restangular‌​.js and it worked. Its very strange.